# Winforms ShowDialog sets Control variable to null

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I use an MVC programming approach where the controller has a reference to its `UserControl` it is controlling.

When clicking on a button on the `UserControl`, I call the following code in the controller:

```
class MyController {
    UserControl targetControl;
    public UserControl TargetControl {
       get { 
         if (targetControl == null) { targetControl = new UserControl();}
         return targetControl;
       }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public void OnButtonClick() {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()) {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                using (MyForm2 f2 = new MyForm2()) {
                    f2.ShowDialog();
                    // when reaching this, targetControl is null....
                    f2.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why this would be, especially that `targetControl.InvokeRequired` returns falls, which I understand as telling me I am actually executing on the UI thread....

**UPDATE**
The reference to the `UserControl` was explicitly set to null by some downstream code, which has indeed nothing to do with `ShowDialog`...

Comment: What do you mean by pointer? Pointers in C#? What am I missing here?

Comment: First: You don't need to call `Dispose` when using `using`. Also: That code doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem, as it is not clear where `targetControl` is even set to `null`. A `UserControl` variable doesn't just become `null`, not even through garbage collection. It becomes disposed, but not null, so there must be at least one location in your code where you explicitly set it to `null` or you never initialize it to anything but `null`. Also, why do you think you should be on any other thread than the UI thread if you don't create one?

Comment: Make sure you not using your private `targetControl` instead of property.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Thanks for the hint, I think I've found the underlying issue, which is that the `Form2` uses the same controller and indeed resets the `targetControl`... apologies for the irrelevancy of the question, your answer still helped me find the bug!